# Vectorized loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, vector, vectorization

Very simple question, but I didn't find anything...

I have to split my code in different sections and run it the following way, because some matrices are built from left to right and some from right to left via backwards induction. For example, if I split it in 3 sections, I would run the sections in this order:

```
1, 2, 3,

1, 2,

1,

1, 2,

1, 2, 3.
```

So I need a vector [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]. But since the number of sections is much greater than 3, I want to build a general vector that goes:

```
1 : noSections

1 : noSections - 1

...

1

...

1 : noSections
```

How would I do that?

Comment: In one sentence: I want to build a vector [1:noSections, 1:noSections-1, 1:noSections-2, ..., 1:1, 1:2, 1:3, ..., 1:noSections].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `arrayfun` which is pretty nice for your job.

```
cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x)1:x, [n:-1:1 2:n], 'UniformOutput', false))
```

Explanation:

```
[n:-1:1 2:n] % create the vector for the last element of each row, i.e. the vector [n, n-1, ..., 1, 2, ..., n]

@(x)1:x % Generate a 1:x vector for each x, this is done for each element of the previous vector
```

For your example:

```
n = 3;
cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x)1:x, [n:-1:1 2:n], 'UniformOutput', false))

ans =

     1     2     3     1     2     1     1     2     1     2     3
```